# ThingsBoard Rulechains - REST API Call with Form URL encoded Body

Tags: rest, http, thingsboard

We would like to fetch data from an external REST API with ThingsBoard Rulechains. In order to this, first we need to get an Auth token for further requests to the API. It is required by the API to send an POST Request with Form URL encoded body like the following:

```
{
 "grant_type": "password",
 "username": "XXX",
 "password": "XXX
}
```

If we try this with ThingsBoard rulechains the following error is returned:

> org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 Unsupported Media Type: [no body]

We also tried setting the **Content-Type** Header Property to **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

In Tools like Insomnia or Postman this works, if we explicitly define the Body to **Form URL encoded**, but ThingsBoard doesn't have this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several posts ([one](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/6567) and [two](https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/2527)) on the official bugtracker where
one suggest to add fake parameters in the front and back of your data and set content type to `x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
var vMsg = "start=start&grant_type=password&username=XXX&password=X&end=end";
return {msg: vMsg, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType};
```